# Live Server Command Not Found, after global install

Tags: javascript, npm-live-server

Anytime I try to run "live-server", I'm getting "bash: live-server: command not found"
I ran "npm install live-server -g"
and "sudo npm install live-server -g"
to install globally.

It was working fine before and then I started getting this issue.
Not building anything just working on a JS course on Udemy.
Total beginner, pretty lost

I tried reinstalling, restarting VS code, restarting my computer, etc.
Zero luck

Comment: Total shot in the dark, but does your version of node change for some reason? You can check it with `node -v` after installing `live-server` and then again when it goes missing

Comment: From what I've noticed the version has been the same but I'll try again

Comment: Running node -v returns the same version regardless. I just tried uninstalling and reinstalling again, running node -v to see the version. Then running live-server again, still get "command not found"

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/UDaI5aX

Comment: are you supposed to install npm packaged with `sudo`? https://medium.com/@ExplosionPills/dont-use-sudo-with-npm-5711d2726aa3

Comment: I just use it because in some courses I've taken they've said sometimes you might need to use it as a Mac user. I'll try running it again without. But the issue has persisted regardless

Comment: Trying without sudo, same result. Install globally, run "live-server", get "command not found"

Comment: Ok. You need to learn to read error messages, it's a very important thing for developers. In your screenshot npm tell you it wants to rename/copy a directory and it can't because it already exists (probably from a previous reinstallation). You need to remove that directory. Can you do it?

Comment: I see. Okay, I'll work on that. Still pretty new to the CL. So I'll work on removing that.

Comment: So I've messed around and solved the "command not found" issue. live server will launch now when I run "live-server".
My issue now, is when it opens the browser window, it never fully loads the page. The "loading" circle just spins continuously until you get a "page unresponsive" prompt.
Seems I'm making progress but not all the way there.
Also never loads to a point in which I can even open the console

Comment: My first guess would be that “page unresponsive” means there’s an infinite loop somewhere

Comment: Hmm that would make sense.  I’ll look into it.  Thanks for your help Mike

Comment: I seem to have found it.  Looks like it is back to normal. Thanks Mike!!